# How to change the field separator of a file using Python?

Tags: python, separator, lidar

I'm new to Python from the R world, and I'm working on big text files, structured in data columns (this is LiDaR data, so generally 60 million + records).

Is it possible to change the field separator (eg from tab-delimited to comma-delimited) of such a big file without having to read the file and do a `for` loop on the lines?

Comment: For what it's worth, if you're on a Linux/UNIX system, this sort of thing may be more easily accomplished with sed: `sed -i 's/\t/,/g' file.csv` (or something like that - don't use this without testing it on a small sample file first).

Comment: @David - Something like %$#"! and then -> please do not use this whitout testing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

- Read the file in
- Change separators for each line
- Write each line back

This is easily doable with just a few lines of Python (not tested but the general approach works):

```
# Python - it's so readable, the code basically just writes itself ;-)
#
with open('infile') as infile:
  with open('outfile', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
      fields = line.split('\t')
      outfile.write(','.join(fields))
```

I'm not familiar with R, but if it has a library function for this it's probably doing exactly the same thing.

Note that this code only reads one line at a time from the file, so the file can be larger than the physical RAM - it's never wholly loaded in.

Comment: You might need to escape any actual `,` characters in the input lines.

Comment: @intuited: Agreed, but it would be even better to use the writing capabilities of the standard `csv` module. My answer is simplistic because the OP's question is simplistic

Comment: R would load the whole file into RAM, thus my concern about efficiency here. Cheers,

Comment: @Pierre: no concern, then ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the linux tr command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-linux-unix-tr-command/) to replace any character with any other character.

Answer (score 1):

Actually lets say yes, you can do it without loops eg:

```
with open('in') as infile:
  with open('out', 'w') as outfile:
      map(lambda line: outfile.write(','.join(line.split('\n'))), infile)
```

Comment: Your code has no effect. [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an iterator and you don't consume it anywhere.

Comment: because I dont need to consume it, are you familiar with map function at all not only in Python world?

Comment: Yes, I am, but for example: `map(lambda x: print(x), [0, 1])` is no-op.

Comment: Yes, and in python 2.x its invalid syntax, or not working because seems print is not a function, anyway there is another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731213/print-doesnt-print-when-its-in-map-python

Comment: Exactly, glad you found the link. You can fix your code then.

Answer (score 0):

You cant, but i strongly advise you to check generators.

Point is that you can make faster and well structured program without need to write and store data in memory in order to process it.

For instance

```
file = open("bigfile","w")
j = (i.split("\t") for i in file)
s = (","join(i) for i in j)
#and now magic happens
for i in s:
     some_other_file.write(i)
```

This code spends memory for holding only single line.

Comment: Is there any reason why ``some_other_file.write(",".join(i.split("\t") for i in file))`` would be worse ? - Also, you must end with ``file.close()``. And better to avoid name of a builtin-in identifier _file_