# Print doesn't print when it's in map, Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
primes = [2,3,5,7..] (prime numbers)
map(lambda x:print(x),primes)
```

It does not print anything.
Why is that?
I've tried

```
sys.stdout.write(x)
```

too, but doesn't work either.

Comment: That's a syntax error in Python 2, so I'd assume Python 3.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Since `lambda x: print(x)` is a syntax error in Python < 3, I'm assuming Python 3. That means `map` returns a generator, meaning to get map to actually call the function on every element of a list, you need to iterate through the resultant generator.

Fortunately, this can be done easily:

```
list(map(lambda x:print(x),primes))
```

Oh, and you can get rid of the lambda too, if you like:

```
list(map(print,primes))
```

But, at that point you are better off with letting print handle it:

```
print(*primes, sep='\n')
```

---

NOTE: I said earlier that `'\n'.join` would be a good idea. That is only true for a list of str's.

Comment: It's still a very bad idea (non-idiomatic, not obvious - map, filter, list comprehensions, etc. are for computations, not for side effects) though. You should just use a for loop, or `print(*primes, sep='\n')`, or `print('\n'.join(str(x) for x in primes))`.

Comment: `print(x)` isn't a syntax error in Python < 3. Edit: Sorry, it's syntax error in this question.

Comment: @utdemir: Occuring in a `lambda` or any other expression, it is (with or without parens). I assume OP meant that and you just want to nitpick on the wording ;)

Comment: list(map(lambda x:print(x) if x>=a and isIntPalindrome(x),primes))
Ok, but why that doesn't work (syntax)

Comment: @matiit: You can't use `if` like that. Try a list comprehension: `[print(x) for x in primes if x >= a and isIntPalindrome(x)]`, however using `print` in a list comprehension like that is still weird. Just use `[x for x in primes if ...]` and then `print` the result of that if you want to see the output.

Comment: Sorry, I'm always using print on my codes, and I just tried doing print("a") in Python 2.7 and 2.5, so just thought it is valid. Thanks for correction.

Comment: If you don't want to iterate over all of `primes` at once, or for some other reason you want separate `print` statements, the Pythonic way is a normal `for` loop, not `list` on a `map` which accumulates the `None`s. If you need to use `map` for some reason, you can avoid `None` accumulation with `next((x for x in map(print, primes) if x != None), None)`, but there is no reason to do that.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> map(lambda x: print(x), primes)
2
3
5
7
17: [None, None, None, None]
```

Are you using Python 2.x where print is a statement, not a function?

Comment: It works specifically because you're using Python 2. In Python 3, it doesn't. And OP is more likely using 3.x since `print` is used as function and since `sys.stdout.write` "doesn't work either".

Comment: you can actually do `map(print, primes)` directly, without defining a lambda function.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can unpack it by putting `*` before `map(...)` like the following

```
[*map(...)]
```

or

```
{*map(...)}
```

Choose the output you desire, a list or a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, I am long gone from python, but that's an elegant way imho.

Answer (score 3):

Another reason why you could be seeing this is that you're not evaluating the results of the map function. It returns a **generator (an iterable)** that evaluates your function **lazily** and not an actual list.

```
primes = [2,3,5,7]
map(print, primes) # no output, because it returns a generator
```

```
primes = [2,3,5,7]
for i in map(print, primes):
    pass # prints 2,3,5,7
```

Alternately, you can do `list(map(print, primes))` which will also force the generator to be evaluated and call the print function on each member of your list.