# Why map(print, a_list) doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, map-function

For a normal function, `map` works well:

```
def increment(n):
    return n+1
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l = map(increment, l)
print l
>>> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

However, if it's `print` being put inside the `map` function:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l = map(print, l)
print l
```

python will complain:

```
l = map(print, l)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What makes `print` special? Doesn't `print(x)` also a valid function call? The above code are tested under python 2.7.

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731213/print-doesnt-print-when-its-in-map-python (this one concerns syntax error -- statement/function difference in Python 2, that one is about `map` being lazy)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't print work in a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970858/why-doesnt-print-work-in-a-lambda) (different use case, same issue about statement/function)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Python 2.x, `print` is a statement, not a function.  If you try this in Python 3.x it will work.

In Python 2.x, you can say `print(x)` and it is not a syntax error, but it isn't actually a function call.  Just as `1 + (3)` is the same as `1 + 3`, `print(x)` is the same as `print x` in Python 2.x.

In Python 2.x you can do this:

```
def prn(x):
    print x
```

Then you can do:

```
map(prn, lst)
```

and it will work.  Note that you probably don't want to do `lst = map(prn, lst)` because `prn()` returns `None`, so you will replace your list of values with a same-length list of just the value `None`.

EDIT: Two other solutions for Python 2.x.

If you want to completely change the behavior of `print`, you can do this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

map(print, lst)
```

This makes `print` into a function just as it is in Python 3.x, so it works with `map()`.

Or, you can do this:

```
from pprint import pprint

map(pprint, lst)
```

`pprint()` is a function that prints things and it is available as a built-in.  I'm not exactly sure how it is different from the default `print` (it says it is a "pretty-print" function but I'm not sure how exactly that makes it different).

Also, according to the PEP 8 standard, it is non-recommended to use `l` as a variable name, so I am using `lst` instead in my examples.

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: It will not blow up, but very likely it will not work as expected. I guess clwen wanted to actually print stuff and not get `<map object at 0x9a62aec>`. If you want to print it, you have to iterate over the map object.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it will not blow up"... if you try running `map(print, [])` in Python 2.x you will get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` because `print` is a statement.  You must have tried it in Python 3.x, where `print` is a function and it's perfectly legal to pass it to `map()`.  In Python 2.x `map()` returns a list, not a `<map object>`.

Comment: I meant: Yes, you're correct, `map(print, [])` will not blow up (throw an exception) in Python 3. But although it does not throw an exception, the result is probably not what clwen wanted to get.

Answer (score 8):

A better way to map print in 2.x would be to do

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: If you do this, you can no longer use `print` as a statement in that module.  As long as that is understood this is a reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, in Python 2.x `print` is a statement.  If you really want to do this in Python 2.x you can use `pprint`:

```
from pprint import pprint
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
p = map(pprint, l)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `print` is not a function.

But you can make print-wrapper, of course:

```
>>> def p(x):
...   print x
... 
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> l = map(p, l)
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 1):

From your line `print l`, I assume this is python2, where `print` is **not** a function, it's a statement.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers work for Python 2, but not in Python 3 with the changes to both map and the print function.

The solution I've arrived at to achieve what I wanted `map(print, lst)` to do in Python 3 is to unpack the list inside of the print call.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
print(*lst, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

You can find more detail around this in my answer to [Use print inside lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42399676/149428).