# Use print inside lambda

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to use print inside lambda. Something like that:

```py
lambda x: print x
```

I understand, that in Python 2.7 print is not a function. So, basically, my question is: Is there a pretty way to use print as function in Python 2.7?

Comment: You have answers telling you how to convert print to a function, but is there a good reason why you don't just write a function instead of a lambda? Then you can have multiple statements and everything. The only cost is that you have to give the function a name.

Comment: @Duncan Because, in my case, it is more readable and simpler.  
For example:   
 
 
     map (lambda x: print (x.encode()), sequence)  Is much better, than defining a function and then mapping it.

Comment: but in that case: `for x in sequence: print(x.encode())` would be so much simpler. Why complicate things? There are times when `lambda` is very useful, but not for that.

Comment: @Duncan Well, in fact, they are equal. In my case (I didn't showed that) I am also use array of encoded values later, which map returns. It is a bit strange, but tastes differ ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can import `print_function` from the `__future__` and use it as a function like this

```
from __future__ import print_function
map(print, [1, 2, 3])
# 1
# 2
# 3
```

Comment: Crap, I use 2.7, always include that import, and never realized this way now possible...

Comment: I know the question is for Python 2, but I'd like to do the same in Python 3.  I thought `map` would work as well, but the output I get with 3.6.0 for `map(print, [1, 2, 3])` is `<map at 0x10bfe3cf8>` which looks like the iterator itself.  Any idea?  Your solution runs fine in Python 2.

Comment: It looks like wrapping the map call like this: `[*map(print, [1,2,3])]` successfully prints in 3, but I'd prefer to just print and not return a list of nulls.

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston To think of it now, this is not so pretty. You might want to simply do `for item in [1, 2, 3]: print(item)`

Comment: @thefourtheye Thanks!  For the project I'm using it in, I'm trying to define this behavior inside a lambda.  One option that came to me this morning to do that is using *args inside the print function, like this: `print(*lst, sep='\n')`.  I'll add this as a separate answer for others.

Comment: I've added an answer below summarizing what worked for me in Python 3.

Answer (score 8):

The question is about Python 2, but I ended up here from Google trying to use the print function inside a lambda in Python 3.  I'm adding this answer for context for others that come here for the same.

*If you only want to see the code that works and not how I arrived there, skip to the last code sample at the bottom.  I wanted to clearly document what didn't work for learning purposes.*

## Desired result

Let's suppose you want to define a lambda `print_list` that prints each item of a list with a newline in between.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]

print_list = lambda lst: ...
```

The desired output is:

```
1
2
3
```

And there should be no unused return value.

## Attempt 1 - A map doesn't evaluate the print function in Python 3

To start, here's what *doesn't work* well in Python 3:

```
map(print, lst)
```

However, the output is somewhat counterintuitively not printed lines, because the map call in Python 3 [returns an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1303354/149428) instead of an evaluated list.

Output:

```
n/a
```

Return value:

```
<map at 0x111b3a6a0>
```

## Attempt 2 - Evaluate the map iterator

You can realize the printing by passing the `map` result to `list(...)`, which produces the ideal output, but has the side effect of returning a list of nulls (as evaluated in the REPL).

```
list(map(print, lst))
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Return value:

```
[None, None, None]
```

You could workaround this by using the underscore [throwaway variable convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python):

```
_ = list(map(print, lst))
```

A similar approach is calling print inside a list comprehension:

```
[print(i) for i in lst]
```

I don't love these approaches because they both still generate an unused return value.

## Attempt 3 - Apply the unpacking operator to the map iterator

Like this:

```
[*map(print, [1, 2, 3])]
```

(This still returns a list of nulls which is non-ideal.)

In the comments above @thefourtheye suggests using a one-line for loop:

```
for item in [1, 2, 3]: print(item)
```

This works fine for most cases and avoids the side effect.  Attempting to put this in a lambda throws a SyntaxError.  I tried wrapping it in parens without success; though there is probably a way to achieve this, I haven't figured it out.

## (SOLUTION!) Attempt 4 - Apply the unpacking operator inside of the print call

The answer I arrived at is to explode the list inside the print call alongside using the separator arg:

```
print(*lst, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

This produces the intended result without a return value.

Finally, let's wrap it up in a lambda to use as desired:

```
print_list = lambda lst: print(*lst, sep='\n')
print_list([1, 2, 3])
```

This was the best solution for my use case in Python 3.

## Related questions

- [Why map(print, a_list) doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768095/why-mapprint-a-list-doesnt-work)
- [Print doesnt print when it's in map, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731213/print-doesnt-print-when-its-in-map-python)

Comment: In Python 3, you should simply use your fourth solution, `print(*lst, sep='\n')`. Thats the best thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to `import from __future__` you can just make the `lambda` write to the standard output:

```
>>>import sys
>>>l = lambda x : sys.stdout.write(x)
>>>l('hi')
'hi'
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is another scenario people may be interested in: "print out the intermediate step value of the lambda function variables"

For instance, say I want to find out the charset of a collection of char list:

```
In [5]: instances = [["C","O","c","1","c","c","c","c","c","1","O","C","C","N","C"],
   ...: ["C","C","O","C","(","=","O",")","C","C","(","=","O",")","c"],
   ...: ["C","N","1","C","C","N","(","C","c","2","c","c","c","(","N"],
   ...: ["C","l","c","1","c","c","c","2","c","(","N","C","C","C","["],
   ...: ["C","C","c","1","c","c","c","(","N","C","(","=","S",")","N"]]
```

one way of doing this is to use reduce:

```
def build_charset(instances):
    return list(functools.reduce((lambda x, y: set(y) | x), instances, set()))
```

In this function, `reduce` takes a `lambda` function with two variables `x, y`, which at the beginning I thought it would be like `x -> instance`, and `y -> set()`. But its results give a different story, so I want to print their value on the fly. `lambda` function, however, only take a single expression, while the print would introduce another one.

Inspired by `set(y) | x`, I tried this one and it worked:

```
lambda x, y: print(x, y) or set(y) | x
```

Note that `print()` is of NoneType, so you cannot do `and`, `xor` these kinds of operation that would change the original value. But `or` works just fine in my case.

Hope this would be helpful to those who also want to see what's going on during the procedure.