# why we can not apply map function to print python?

Tags: python, printing

I wonder why 'print' can not be used in python map function? 
I assume print is also a function so this should work as map works on functions as documentation: `map(function, iterable, ...)`

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
map(print,a)
```

Comment: You actually can...

Comment: Do you know what `print` does?  Do you know what it returns?

Comment: Why is this tagged `dictionary`?

Comment: I think you cannot in python 2 because print is a function only in python 3.

Comment: you should tag this question as "python 2" because it's very likely a python-2 only problem.

Comment: @scott, print prints the items given to it in python. Adding dictionary was a mistake sorry for that.

Comment: @ScottHunter: if you want to tag it with `map`, it gives `dictionary`. Might be an explanation.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: `from __future__ import print_function` would make it work in Python 2 as well..

Comment: @Willem, You are right about the tag. I first tried map but got a dictionary. I do not have reputation to add a tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why map(print, a_list) doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768095/why-mapprint-a-list-doesnt-work) (if Python 2) or [Print doesn't print when it's in map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731213/print-doesnt-print-when-its-in-map-python) (if Python 3)

Answer (score 2):

You are not iterating over the `map()` object, so no function calls are made. `map()` does not immediately apply the calls; only as you drab results from the iterator, are elements from the input sequence drawn and have the `print()` function applied.

If you looped over the `map()` object the code works; for example, by using the `list()` call:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> it = map(print, a)
>>> list(it)
1
2
3
4
[None, None, None, None]
```

Answer (score 1):

In [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) you actually **can** apply `print` in a `map`. The `print` will **always return `None`** but that's not really a problem.

The only problem with [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) is that **`map` works lazy**: it returns a generator that will only calculate elements if they are needed. In order to get Python to work, you need to **materialize** the outcome of `map` somehow. You can for instance do this with `list(..)`:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a=[1,2,3,4]
>>> list(map(print,a))
1
2
3
4
[None, None, None, None]
```

In [pyton-2.7](/questions/tagged/pyton-2.7), `print` is **not a function** and thus you cannot provide it to `map`.

Comment: Willem, Thanks for the reply. why is it printing none?Should it be printing elements in the list as defined by the definition of map?

Comment: @curious: because the `print` function does **not `return`s** something and in that case Python will let it return `None`. So the last line is the result of the map.

Comment: Got it, It returns none because print does not return anything

Comment: @curious: indeed, it prints on the stdout, but does not - in any case - generates a result.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, `print` is not a function so `map(print,[])` triggers invalid syntax.

Python 2 workaround would be to use a *real* function to write to standard output. `sys.stdout.write` would almost be a candidate, but you have to add a linefeed + string conversion to roughly emulate what `print` does:

```
map(lambda x: sys.stdout.write(str(x)+"\n"),a)
```

It works in python 3 (but `map` doesn't unless you force iteration)

EDIT: `from __future__ import print_function` also allows to use `print` as a function