# Why does map(print, x) return "None" value list?

Tags: python, dictionary, printing, nonetype

In Python 3.5, the code

```
>>> T = map(print, [1, 2, 3])
>>> type(T)
<class 'map'>
```

returns a map object. I would expect this map object T to contain the numbers 1, 2 and 3; all on separate lines.
In actuality, this *does* happen. The only problem is that it also outputs a list of `None`values the same length as the input list.

```
>>> list(T)
1
2
3
[None, None, None]
>>>
```

This is repeatable for any input I use, not just the arbitrary integer list shown above.
Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: `print` returns `None`. `map` collects return values of function against iterable items.

Comment: `print(print(1))`

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4):

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7731274
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11768129
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42399676

Each `None` that you see is what `print` function **returns**. To understand what `map` does, try the following code:

```
>>> T = map(lambda x: x**2, [1, 2, 3])
>>> t = list(T)
>>> print(t)
[1, 4, 9]
```

When you use `print` instead:

```
>>> T = map(print, [1, 2, 3])
>>> t = list(T)
1
2
3
>>> print(t)
[None, None, None]
```

This is not surprising, because:

```
>>> a = print("anything")
anything
>>> print(a)
None
```