# Python Java forEach equivalent

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, lambda

I am Java programmer. I started learning Python few days ago.
I'm wondering: are there any equivalents to

```
map.forEach(System.out::println)
```

in Python with lambdas?
Or only with for loop:

```
for e in map: print(e)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no equivalent to Java's imperative `Iterable.forEach` or `Stream.forEach` method. There's a `map` function, analogous to Java's `Stream.map`, but it's for applying transformations to an iterable. Like Java's `Stream.map`, it doesn't actually apply the function until you perform a terminal operation on the return value.

You could abuse `map` to do the job of `forEach`:

```
list(map(print, iterable))
```

but it's a bad idea, producing side effects from a function that shouldn't have any and building a giant list you don't need. It'd be like doing

```
someList.stream().map(x -> {System.out.println(x); return x;}).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

in Java.

The standard way to do this in Python would be a loop:

```
for thing in iterable:
    print(thing)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python also has a `map` function and it uses the syntax `map(function, iterable, ...)`

See Python docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Comment: But why this: a = {1, 2, 3}
map(lambda x: print(x), a) - won't print anything?

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731213/print-doesnt-print-when-its-in-map-python

I hope it answers your question :)

Comment: @Don_Quijote map returns a new list with the same number of elements as the original list. The print function does however not return something. So it is not possible to create this new list.

Comment: @Don_Quijote you could however create a new function def custom_print(x): print(x); return x with side effects and then use map(custom_print, a) But I rather don't advise such practices

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention the [`streamable`](https://github.com/ebonnal/streamable) module I wrote (would love to get feedback!):

Your example would look like:

```py
from streamable import Stream

Stream(lambda: ["foo", "bar"]).foreach(print).exhaust()
```

```
foo
bar
```

- this is a ***typed*** module with 100% code coverage and no dependency
- the `Stream[T]` class extends `Iterable[T]`
- a stream is ***immutable***
- operations are ***lazily evaluated*** and cover concurrency, grouping/flattening, exceptions catching, rate limiting, iteration progress logging, ...