# trying to return items form a list one at a time

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

so i'm trying to make an app that prints the same sentence with different names, so using a function i want to return the names(to use them in another function) and it always only returns the first name and ends.i tried solving this using many ways and couldn't find a solution any one can help?

```
def next_person(list):
    i = 0
    while i < len(list):
        if i < len(list):
            return list[i]
        i += 1

names = ("nike", "dan", "someone", "elzein", "joe")

print(next_person(names))
```

Comment: When you return inside the `while`, the function is complete and any state, including the current value of `i` is deleted. In this example you seem to only be reimplementing the standard list iteration protocol, for instance, the program could do `for name in names:`.

Comment: Not clear why you feel you need a function. Why not just: `for n in names: print(f"sentence: {n}")`?

Comment: Its not clear from your example how you plan to user this function. Do you want to call it multiple times in a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certainly simpler ways to do it but if you need to return items one at a time [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) is what you need

you can use map to print the value and call list to [evaluate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7731243/4626485) it

```
def next_person(list):
    i = 0
    while i < len(list):
        if i < len(list):
             yield list[i]
        i += 1

names = ("nike", "dan", "someone", "elzein", "joe")

list(map(print, next_person(names)))
```

Comment: But `list(map(print, names))` does the same thing. There is no reason to build a generator to iterate something that is already iterable.

Comment: @tdelaney as i said there are simpler ways to do it, You can do it in one line 
`print(*("nike", "dan", "someone", "elzein", "joe"), sep='\n')`

Comment: Its not just that there are simpler ways to do it, it should not be done this way at all. OP seems to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how lists work. That's what we should focus on.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the function at all. `list` supports the python iterator protocol. There is no need to wrap it in something that tries to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest using a for loop :

```
def next_person(list):
        for a in list:
                print("This is my sentence : {}".format(a))

names = ["nike", "dan", "someone", "elzein", "joe"]

next_person(names)

Output :
This is my sentence : nike
This is my sentence : dan
This is my sentence : someone
This is my sentence : elzein
This is my sentence : joe
```

Comment: I think the real problem is that there shouldn't be a `next_person` function at all. It seems OP is just trying to recreate python's existing iteration protocol. We would need to see a larger example what OP wants to do to answer.

Comment: ok, but what if i want to use the output of this function in another function how can it be solved?

Comment: If you want to use the output, instead of print. You should create an empty list and append the result to the list.  You would then get a list containing the outputs. But again, I do not know what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

By calling return you are ending the function
if you want your function to do as you say it would have to be written as

```
def next_person(list):
    i = 0
    while i < len(list):
        if i < len(list):
            print(list[i])
        i += 1

names = ("nike", "dan", "someone", "elzein", "joe")

next_person(names)
```

if you want to return the generated sentences

```
def next_person(list):
    i = 0
    sentences = []
    while i < len(list):
        if i < len(list):
           sentences.append(list[i])
        i += 1
    return(sentences)

names = ("nike", "dan", "someone", "elzein", "joe")

mySentences = next_person(names)
print(mySentences)

Output :
["nike", "dan", "someone", "elzein", "joe"]
```

Comment: ok, but what if i want to use the output of this function in another function how can it be solved?

Comment: you can create a list variable in the beginning of your function, append the answers to it, and then return the list at the end of your function